# How to manage JWT properly using React?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I am builing a member system with a lot of function like memo or post system...etc, so I think it's more safe to use JWT token, so I let my api return jwt token every time I sign in like below

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "",
    "data": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MGViYzI0MDRhNmVkNDU2NzUwOTk4YjEiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImpvaG4iLCJleHAiOjE2MjY5NTgwMzEuMjA3LCJpYXQiOjE2MjYzNTMyMzF9.3t_YzKPq4jk6UuIkzTgFaLoXD0Pq5ktmRFp7xg6dFYU"
}
```

And it contains userID and userName , but here's the problem , every time I have to use something else like userProfilePicture ,userFriend...etc , I have to make an API request, it's really meaningless to do

eventually I manage it like I used axio.interceptor to verify and before I assign my data to context state I fetch user's all data using this token and assign the data to state , Is'nt it the same way to just return all user's data without JWT?.

It seems to me that JWT Token is kind of useless, can anyone tell me that what's the real ,effiecent way to use JWT Token and what's the common managment?

Comment: I use jwt for authorization and therefore prevent unauthorized people (eg. people that aren't logged in to the application) to access data that they shouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can save your token JWT in localstorage... and call it in header of request (or fetch) when you call api...

But dont forget to set expired token of JWT to one week (or one month, or one year... its up to you)...

Or you can set configuration if your JWT, if your token is expired, it will still send the response to your app....

Comment: local storage , that's why , thank you for the answer